# (matlab) how to load adaboost model so that coder compatible?

Tags: matlab, adaboost

I save my adaboot model as .mat file. I use this to load the model:

```
load('adaboost_23.mat')
```

But matlab coder cannot generate C/C++ code. So I change to:

```
coder.load('adaboost_23.mat')
```

Still not working:

[image: error message]

How should I do it? Data type is `ClassificationEnsemble`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I know. According to matlab guidance, you have to compact model first.

```
mdl = load('train_model.mat');
saveLearnerForCoder(mdl, 'compacted_model');
```

And load model.

```
cpt = loadLearnerForCoder('compacted_model');
```

After that, Coder will hard code your model and you will get your model in cpp file.